# Слайдер в joomla на второстепенной странице.

Tags: slider, joomla, php, html, css

Доброго дня у.в. профи, вопрос вот какой:
Все нормальные люди ставят слайдер на главной странице сайта, но передо мной стоит задача - установить его на второстепенную страницу сайта на джумле. Как поставить слайдер на главную, уроков и рассказов много, а вот на второстепенную - что-то я не нашел. Помогите, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать модуль, при настройках модуля там есть блок **Назначение меню**, переключить на **Выбрать из списка**, отметить где(на каких страницах) он будет отображаться.